# Aggregate duplicate documents with values in array in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection of documents that look as follows:

```json
{ "_id": "5a760191813a54000b8475f1", "orders": [{ "row": "3", "seat": "11" }, { "row": "3", "seat": "12" }], "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614" },
{ "_id": "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05e", "orders": [{ "row": "3", "seat": "12" }, { "row": "3", "seat": "13" }], "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614" },
{ "_id": "5a75ebdf813a54000b8475e7", "orders": [{ "row": "5", "seat": "16" }, { "row": "5", "seat": "15" }], "product_id": "5a75f711dbcc42000c459efc" }
```

I need to be able to find any documents where the `product_id` and items in the `orders` array are duplicates. I can't quite seem to wrap my head around accomplishing this. Any pointers?

Comment: duplicates you mean same product_id and have at least one common order?
For example above there is duplicate because of  `{ "row": "3", "seat": "12" }`?
And what output data you would like to get after the query?For example only the "_id" of the duplicates would be enough?Or you want to keep all the document information?

Comment: all elemnts of orders must be duplicated ?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what output you want, but this has the information about the duplicates, maybe you want to add unwind on duplicates also.

Result documents

- product_id
- order (that found duplicated)
- duplicates (the documents that had that order as duplicate)

For your data would print

```js
[{
  "duplicates": [
    "5a760191813a54000b8475f1",
    "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05e"
  ],
  "order": {
    "row": "3",
    "seat": "12"
  },
  "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614"
}]
```

Query
(run it on your driver, MongoPlayground doesn't keep the order of fields and can show wrong results)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind" : {"path" : "$orders"}},
 {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : {
      "orders" : "$orders",
      "product_id" : "$product_id"
    },
    "duplicates" : {
      "$push" : "$_id"
    }
  }
 },
 {"$match" : {"$expr" : {"$gt" : [ {"$size" : "$duplicates"}, 1 ]}}},
 {
  "$project" : {
    "_id" : 0,
    "order" : "$_id.orders",
    "product_id" : "$_id.product_id",
    "duplicates" : 1
  }
 } 
])
```

Data (i added some more data)

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "5a760191813a54000b8475f1",
    "orders": [
      {
        "row": "3",
        "seat": "11"
      },
      {
        "row": "3",
        "seat": "12"
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05g",
    "orders": [
      {
        "row": "3",
        "seat": "12"
      },
      {
        "row": "3",
        "seat": "13"
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05e",
    "orders": [
      {
        "row": "3",
        "seat": "12"
      },
      {
        "row": "3",
        "seat": "13"
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a75ebdf813a54000b8475e7",
    "orders": [
      {
        "row": "5",
        "seat": "16"
      },
      {
        "row": "5",
        "seat": "15"
      }
    ],
    "product_id": "5a75f711dbcc42000c459efc"
  }
]
```

Results

```js
[{
  "duplicates": [
    "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05g",
    "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05e"
  ],
  "order": {
    "row": "3",
    "seat": "13"
  },
  "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614"
},
{
  "duplicates": [
    "5a760191813a54000b8475f1",
    "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05g",
    "5a75f6f17abe45000a3ba05e"
  ],
  "order": {
    "row": "3",
    "seat": "12"
  },
  "product_id": "5a7628bedbcc42000aa7f614"
}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use below query. $unwind the orders array, $group by order row and product and collect matching ids and count. Keep the documents where count is greater than 1. $lookup to pull in the matching documents by id and $replaceRoot to flatten the documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$orders"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "order": "$orders",
        "product_id": "$product_id"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "doc_ids": {
        "$push": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "doc_ids",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "documents"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$documents"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$documents"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YbztEGttUMx

Answer (score 2):

While this can be done purely in Mongo I do not recommend it as it's very very very memory inefficient. you basically have to hold the entire collection in memory the entire time while you do certain manipulations on it.

I will however show the pipeline for this because we will use it with the second more scaleable approach.

We want to `$group` based on `orders` and `product_id`, however there are 2 issues standing in our way.

1. The `orders` field might not be sorted the same in all documents, because Mongo does not support "nested" sorting we have to `$unwind` the array, `$sort` it and restore the original structure. ( mind you you're sorting the entire collection here in memory ). This step which is one of the pain points of this pipeline can be skipped if you can ensure sort order is maintained in the `orders` array.
2. Mongo is inconsistent when `$group`ing an array of objects. full disclosure I'm not entirely sure what's going on in there but I'm guessing there are some "shortcuts" done for efficiency which affects the stability somehow. So our approach will be to convert these objects into a string (concating the "row" and "seat" together).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$orders"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "orders.row": 1,
      "orders.seat": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      tmpOrders: {
        $push: {
          $concat: [
            "$orders.row",
            "$orders.seat"
          ]
        }
      },
      product_id: {
        $first: "$product_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        orders: "$tmpOrders",
        product: "$product_id"
      },
      dupIds: {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "dupIds.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      dups: "$dupIds",
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f_bARscFfnS)

Now as I said this approach is not scaleable, and on large collections will take a very long time to run. So I recommend utilizing indexes and iterating over `product_id`'s and executing each pipeline separately.

```
// wraps the native Promise, not required.
import Bluebird = require('bluebird');

// very fast with index.
const productIds = await collection.distinct('product_id')

await Bluebird.map(productIds, async (productId) => {
    const dups = await collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                product_id: productId
            }
        }
         ... same pipeline ...
    ])
    
    if (dups.length) {
        // logic required.
    }
    // can control concurrency based on db workload.
}, { concurrency: 5})
```

Make sure with this approach you have an index built on `product_id` so it will work efficiently.